# Workflow Foundation String Comparison

Tags: c#, .net, workflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phG8h.png)

I am trying to do a simple string comparison in Workflow foundation. The workflow does not take me to "Then" on any case. Am I missing some basic checks. Appreciate your help.

```
doc.GetType().Name
docname = "DOC1"
compareresult = String.Equals(docname, "DOC1")
compareresult.ToString()
```

Comment: What do you get displayed in Console?

Comment: It was a wired behavior. Post restart of machine, it started working fine..